Airflow conn_id isn't defined error with Airflow 2.7.2
I am facing an issue with conn_id isn't defined error with Airflow 2.7.2 version but this connection is already present in the connection list.
This issue is happening intermittently, and this error resulted into DAG import error on the airflow UI Screen.
enter image description here
Exception logs
 File "/opt/airflow/plugins/domainp/utils/utilities.py", line 112, in on_retry_callback
    retry_duration_limit = float(get_config_macro(task_ins, "retry_tasks_failed_within_seconds"))
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/domainp/utils/config.py", line 204, in get_config_macro
    config = get_configs_macro(
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/domainp/utils/config.py", line 245, in get_configs_macro
    filter_entries(get_pgcc_config(dataset_pcd_rendered, prefix), prefix)
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/domainp/utils/config.py", line 276, in get_pgcc_config
    grpc_hook = GrpcServiceHook("shared_service_conn")
  File "/opt/airflow/plugins/domainp/service/hooks/service.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.conn = self.get_connection(self.conn_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base.py", line 72, in get_connection
    conn = Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(conn_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 477, in get_connection_from_secrets
    raise AirflowNotFoundException(f"The conn_id `{conn_id}` isn't defined")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `shared_service_conn` isn't defined 
the Connection fetch code:
class GrpcServiceHook(BaseHook):
    """Grpc service hook"""


Connection retrieve code
def __init__(self, conn_id) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conn_id = conn_id
        self.conn = self.get_connection(self.conn_id)

Please provide suggestions

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
